# Selecting a whole column as a range rather than a named range

Tags: vba, excel

## What I have:

1. I have drop-down list in my form that I'm populating from a
   worksheet.
2. My code only works for named ranges.

## What I need:

I need to populate my drop-down list from a whole column rather than a named range.

## My VBA code:

**Working code using a named range:**

```
'Populate drop-down list (combo box) from range...
Dim range_b As Range

For Each range_b In Worksheets("2.1 Clients").Range("ClientList")
  With Me.cs_ClientName1
    .AddItem range_b.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = range_b.Offset(0, 1).Value
  End With
Next range_b
```

## What I've tried:

I've tried various permutations of the `For Each` line:

```
'For Each range_b In Worksheets("2.1 Clients").Columns(4)
'For Each range_b In Worksheets("2.1 Clients").Range(Columns(4))
'For Each range_b In Worksheets("2.1 Clients").Columns("D:D")
```

...that last of which seems to causing Excel to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more sensible to use Named Range instead of fixing it in code. Imagine someone added a column before D! You would have to change all codes that are hard coded. It is also better to put the With block on top of the For loop. You may also need to Clear the list before it.

Just make sure the named range **ClientList** refers to **Worksheets("2.1 Clients").Range("D:D")**. If you have done that, use below:

```
With Me.cs_ClientName1
    For Each range_b In ThisWorkbook.Names("ClientList").RefersToRange
        If Not IsEmpty(range_b) Then
            .AddItem range_b.Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = range_b.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next range_b
End With
```

A Better performance can be achieved if:

1. List contains a header, with data starts right below it
2. **ClientList** points to the Header, say D1 in Worksheets("2.1 Clients")

Code:

```
' Data Starts right below the Header (Named Range)
Set range_b = ThisWorkbook.Names("ClientList").RefersToRange.Offset(1,0)
With Me.cs_ClientName1
    .Clear ' Clear existing data
    Do Until IsEmpty(range_b)
        .AddItem range_b.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = range_b.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Set range_b = range_b.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End With
Set range_b = Nothing
```

Comment: Returns "End With" without "With" error. I've tried changing the third last line to "End If" and "End If Not" but no luck. (I've created the named range as advised.)

Comment: Updated, but this may have performance impact as it will go through all the rows in the range. You can have fast performance if **ClientList** is a table header and change a bit of the code.

Comment: Both work but I can't work out how to discount the header cell of approach two ("Client", the header cell, is populating in my drop-down list). Is it as simple as setting D2 as my named range instead of D1?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for the robust answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each range_b In Worksheets("2.1 Clients").Range("D:D")
```

**RANGE()** is happy with a string address.

**Edit#1:**

Here is a working example:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim range_b As Range
    For Each range_b In Worksheets("2.1 Clients").Range("D:D")
        If range_b.Value = "good" Then
            MsgBox "good found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next range_b
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason Excel crashes when I apply the above code. I can't think of a reason why. At a guess, I'd say that Excel is endlessly looping through the column. The column consists of five rows with text in each cell. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to reproduce your working code on my end. It's a useful confirmation of the range. I was unable to stitch it together with my original code without producing the same "crashing" effect.